# Django rest url routers on class based views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to get the details of my submodules on a route with multiple parameters.
My existing routes right now are:

- http://localhost:8000/api/module/ -  Gets all modules
- http://localhost:8000/api/module/1/ - Gets all modules and connected submodules

I would like to do http://localhost:8000/api/module/1/submodules/1 which will get the details of the submodules. How should i do this using class based views?

Below is my existing code:

**Views.py**

```
class CourseModuleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CourseModule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseModuleSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        coursemodule = CourseModule.objects.get(id=pk)
        submodule = SubModule.objects.filter(submodule_module_id=pk)

        serializer = SubModuleSerializer(submodule, many=True)
        response = {'message': 'Sucess!',
            'result': serializer.data}
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class CourseModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseModule
        fields = ['class_id', 'coursemodule_title', 'coursemodule_date_created',
            'coursemodule_last_modified', 'coursemodule_created_by']

class SubModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    submodule_module_id = CourseModuleSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = SubModule
        fields = ['submodule_module_id','submodule_title', 'submodule_date_created', 'submodule_last_modified',
            'submodule_created_by']
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('module', CourseModuleViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [drf-nested-routers.](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers)

You would need to include an extra NestedRouter in you urls.py like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'module', CourseModuleViewSet)

sub_modules_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'module', lookup='module')
sub_modules_router.register(r'submodules', SubModuleViewSet, base_name='module-submodules')


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(sub_modules_router.urls)),
)
```

And then you can create a SubModuleViewSet like this:

```
class SubModuleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return SubModule(submodule_module_id =self.kwargs['module_pk'])

    serializer_class = SubModuleSerializer
```

Comment: Perfect! This helped me lot!